# Variable selection, variable reduction, and handling sparsity for binary text classification

Tags: classification, feature-selection, text-mining, data-preprocessing, feature-engineering

I am trying to do a binary text classification using support vector machine. I am wondering if I am doing it right and I'd like to look for some answers to the questions  in mind. The following questions are what I wonder in mind:

1. Should I apply dimension reduction for my binary text classification if the number of cariables are more than 100? If not, when should I consider dimension reduction?
2. Is onehot encoding always applied for binary text classification using support vector machine?
3. What else input feature representations can I have for binary text classification to use support vector machine?
4. How can I tell a text feature is sparse and what can I do about it?
5. Can I apply forward and backward variable selections to choose a subset of variables for my text binary classofication?

Hope to hear some answers.